# Extracting rows based on a value and proximity to another row?

Tags: r, timestamp, diff

I'm trying to extract rows based on a value condition then any row that comes before that row. Take for example the following sample:

```
library(data.table)


latemail <- function(N, st="2012/01/01", et="2012/01/07") {
  st <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(st))
  et <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(et))
  dt <- as.numeric(difftime(et,st,unit="sec"))
  ev <- sort(runif(N, 0, dt))
  rt <- st + ev

}

#create our data frame
set.seed(42)
dt = latemail(100000)
work = setDT(as.data.frame(dt))
work$worker = stringi::stri_rand_strings(1000, 5)   
work$dt = as.POSIXct(as.character(work$dt), tz = "GMT")

#order
work = work[order(work$worker, work$dt),]

#apply difftime
options(scipen=999)
work[, time_diff:= c(NA, diff(dt)), by = worker] 
work$time_diff = as.numeric(work$time_diff)
```

assuming the differences between dates for each worker to be in seconds, how would I extract rows that show a `diff` of 900 seconds, and in addition any row that is adjacent, coming before it?

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify if the answer should be using data.table or something else.
I use `dplyr`. As you want both rows between witch the difference is > 900 seconds, I compare the current row with the previous row but also with the next row, using `lead` and `lag`

```
library(dplyr)

work %>% group_by(worker) %>% arrange(worker, dt) %>%
  filter((dt-lag(dt))>'0.25 hours'|(lead(dt)-dt)>'0.25 hours')
```